# Jquery submit() does not work like pressing submit button

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to build a auto-login button for my demo system (phpBB forum).

This should automatically enter the login details and then submit the login form:

```
$('#autologin').click(function () {
    $('#navloginform input[name="username"], #navloginform input[name="password"]').val('demo');
    $('#navloginform').submit();
});
```

The inserting of the fields works, but submitting the form does not login the user. I also tried to fill the fields myself and then submitted the form in the console, but this does not work either. Pressing the submit button works as expected.

Can somebody help me?

**edit:** Solved it with: `$('#navloginform button[type="submit]').trigger('click');`

Comment: Can you post the relevant _HTML_?

Comment: `click` is just an event binding. You need to trigger it. Put this below the click block. `$('#autologin').trigger('click');`

Comment: @VictorLevin the click event should listen, if the autologin button is pressed, so thats fine. But the trigger click thing worked :)

Comment: @VictorLevin you should copy your comment to an Answer so OP can mark and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with: `$('#navloginform button[type="submit]').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 0):

That's good that you solved it. Your problem was that you used the same ID for more that one element. as rule: ID's have to be unique. If you just changed the submit button id to... #submitBtn (for example) then
 `$(" #submitBtn ").trigger('click');`